# Retrieve facebook friend's id in javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-friends

I'm looking for a snippet to get ids of friends who use my app.

I wrote this:

```
FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
    amis = response.data;
    console.log(amis[].id);
});
```

On login I asked for {scope:'public_profile , user_friends'});

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friends/

Comment: Doc doesn't help me much, i am a begineer.
Fb dev gave exemples to loggin etc... I'm looking for an easy snippet or exemple i can adapt.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the problem is, but you can try this if you just want to output all ids:

```
FB.api('/me/friends', (response) => {
    if (response && response.data) {
        for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            console.log(response.data[i].id);
        }
    }
});
```